# Setting up data set in R

Tags: r

I had a question regarding how to set up the data set in the problem below.  By no means am I asking anyone to solve the entire problem, I was just hoping to get assistance so I could start parts a and b!

I know:

```
x1<-rnorm(40,4,4)
x2<-rnorm(40,10,9)
```

Any advice on how to code for the logistic function?

The question is the photo below:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `rnorm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate that data using `rnorm` and `mlply` from plyr package if you want to do it all at once.

From [this paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/progress?id=nflhIsAhAZ&dl) you can realize that:

> Using `m*ply` with `rnorm()`, `m*ply(data, rnorm)`. The function is called once for each row, with arguments given by the columns. Arguments are matched by position, or name, if present.

```
> x1<-c(40,4,4)  # don't forget using `c` to concatenate elements in a vector
> x2<-c(40,10,9)
> library(plyr)
> set.seed(1)
> mlply(rbind(x1, x2), rnorm)
$`1`
 [1]  1.4941848  4.7345733  0.6574856 10.3811232  5.3180311  0.7181265  5.9497162  6.9532988
 [9]  6.3031254  2.7784465 10.0471247  5.5593729  1.5150377 -4.8587995  8.4997237  3.8202656
[17]  3.9352389  7.7753448  7.2848848  6.3756053  7.6759095  7.1285452  4.2982599 -3.9574068
[25]  6.4793030  3.7754850  3.3768180 -1.8830095  2.0873998  5.6717662  9.4347182  3.5888491
[33]  5.5506864  3.7847798 -1.5082382  2.3400217  2.4228402  3.7627464  8.4001015  7.0527030

$`2`
 [1]  8.5192876  7.7197449 16.2726704 15.0099688  3.8011987  3.6325436 13.2812377 16.9167963
 [9]  8.9888841 17.9299695 13.5829529  4.4917625 13.0700772 -0.1642679 22.8972133 27.8235991
[17]  6.6950067  0.6027884 15.1274766  8.7845086 31.6145598  9.6468400 16.2076543 10.2520194
[25]  3.3105411 11.6991307 -6.2446277 23.1899938 11.3792800 29.5535050 14.2795858  3.6104821
[33] 15.4965372  1.5931213 -1.2827006 12.6230161  6.0103731 10.0099482 10.6690719  4.6943115

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "array"
attr(,"split_labels")
      structure(c(" 4", "10"), class = "AsIs") structure(c("4", "9"), class = "AsIs")
x1 40                                        4                                      4
x2 40      

                             10                                      9
```

Comment: For generating the data, instead of using "c", I believe "rnorm" should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone.  Any advice on how to code logistic function?  I am new to R, I am sure these are pretty basic questions.

Comment: @user3573811 see `glm` for logit estimation. You can estimate a logit model by using `mylogit <- glm(y ~ x1+x2+...+xn, data = mydata, family = "binomial")` where `y` is your response variable and `x's` are your regressors

Comment: OP is probably not trying to estimate a logit model but rather generate data from the formula in originla question. In that case, all that is needed is representing the logistic formula in R notation, which pretty much just involves retyping it verbatim along with appropriately placed parentheses.

Comment: Oh yes, I was wrong, I missread the OP's comment, thanks Thomas